# How to share a page for two or more users?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have theoretical problem. For fist, I need to show you my app:
[image]

As you can see you can create database using ER diagrams and generete some SQL code. After click button you will be able to create your own schema in my localdatabase. Each user can create unlimited schemas.

Well here is my question:
**How to allow two or more users to work on the same diagram at the same time?**

How is this resolved in similar applications?
Online database wizards generate a link that anyone can access and then such a group of people is working on a diagram at the same time.
Is it difficult to program something like this?
Can someone give me some tips how to achieve such a thing?

*I am using: java 1.8, spring boot, hibernate, js, jquery*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets incredibly complicated, fast. The problem is merging. *IF* some given data (such as the Person box) is edited in conflicting ways at the same time by two different users, you have some choices to make:

- Deny the edit entirely by whomever goes 'second', and show them an error.
- Put in more effort to attempt to merge the changes (it is, however, impossible to always succeed unless you have append-only datasets and ordering or decision basis doesn't matter; that's not usually the case).
- Make everything as live as can be. You type something, everybody who is also editing it sees it ASAP. If folks are suffering from slow network connections, clashes just kinda happen and mess things up; so be it.
- Don't allow simultaneous editing at all of anything where merge conflicts could ever occur (so one user can edit box 1, and another can edit box 2, but they can't both edit the same box).

The 'cooler' answers are obviously far more complicated.

Some examples / approaches:

- In general it is a great idea to version everything; have ID numbers (or timestamps, but then you do have to ensure your clocks never run backwards; some ntp daemons can do that. Leap seconds and such are a thing, so this is harder than it sounds like), and every actual edit always has 'I was working on the version with ID X, and now I want it to look like Y' – so that you can deny such edits if the current version in your db is no longer X. With transactional DBs this is guaranteed to never fail.
- If you want to just error out for simultaneous edits, the above is all you need.
- Simultaneous editing would strongly be helped with some chat. Google Docs is the obvious example for this kind of technology. It's obviously QUITE complicated and heavy on the server.
- If you're going to go with the 'no simultaneous edits' routine, then to edit a resource, the client requests the lock from the server, and once it is done, it relinquishes the lock. If the lock is already handed out, your server either waits, or, shows an error. (You can serve up a read only version of course). But make sure that some active pinging thing is happening; you wouldn't want a resource to be 'stuck' locked if someone client trips over a network cable!